Connect to a USB device using electron
I am using navigator.usb.requestDevice to get a USB device. I am able to get the device I wanted i.e. Thermal printer. But when call device.open() it always throws an error Device was disconnected. When do the same thing in browser it works. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is code sample I am trying.

renderer.js

const list = <ul on:click={(e) => {
  const { address, type } = e.target.dataset;
  if (!address) return;
  ipcRenderer.send(
    type === 'bluetooth' ? 'select-bluetooth-device' : 'select-usb-device',
    address,
  );
  dialog.hide();
  bluetoothSelectorShown = false;
}}></ul>;

const usbDevices = [];
let dialog;
let deviceSelectorShown = false;

async function listUsbPrinters(callback) {
      const devices = await navigator.usb.getDevices();
      devices.push(...usbDevices);
      usbDevices.length = 0;
      usbDevices.push(...devices);
      try {
        const requestedDevice = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
          filters: [{ vendorId: 1110 }],
        });
        if (!requestedDevice.opened) {
          await requestedDevice.open();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        toast(error.message);
      }
      callback.success([]);
    }

ipcRenderer.on('found-usb-devices', (event, deviceList) => {
  if (!deviceSelectorShown) {
    deviceSelectorShown = true;
    devices = [];
    list.innerHTML = '';
    list.append(<li className='loading'>Loading...</li>);
    dialog = <Dialog className='select' onhide={() => ipcRenderer.send('select-usb-device', '')}>
      <div className='header'>Select printer</div>
      <div className='body'>{list}</div>
    </Dialog>;
  }

  deviceList.forEach((device) => {
    const { productName, deviceId } = device;
    if (devices[deviceId]) return;
    devices[deviceId] = device;
    list.prepend(<li data-address={deviceId} data-type='usb'>{productName.trim()}</li>);
  });
});

ipcRenderer.on('usb-device-added', (event, device) => {
  list.prepend(<li data-address={device.deviceId} data-type='usb'>{device.productName.trim()}</li>);
});

ipcRenderer.on('usb-device-removed', (event, device) => {
  const $li = list.get(`[data-address="${device.deviceId}"]`);
  $li?.remove();
});


main.js

  win.webContents.session.on('select-usb-device', (event, details, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    selectUsbDeviceCallback = callback;
    win.webContents.send('found-usb-devices', details.deviceList);
  });

  win.webContents.session.on('usb-device-added', (event, device) => {
    win.webContents.send('usb-device-added', device);
  });

  win.webContents.session.on('usb-device-removed', (event, device) => {
    win.webContents.send('usb-device-removed', device);
  });

  ipcMain.on('select-usb-device', (event, device) => {
    selectUsbDeviceCallback(device);
  });

  win.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission) => {
    if (permission === 'usb') {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });

  win.webContents.session.setDevicePermissionHandler((details) => {
    if (details.deviceType === 'usb') {
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  });

